# Assign variable sized array to fixed sized array c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a buffer of chars defined as `char *buffer`.  When I send my XBEE packet data, there is a fixed size requirement (84 bytes).  My problem is I don't know how to convert the buffer into 84 byte chunks as I iterate.  Here is what I get:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     packet = (buffer + i);
            ^
```

And my code:

```
int sendSerialBuffer(char *buffer, int length)
{
  int i = 0;
  int result = 0;
  char (* packet)[84];

  // Iterate through all the bytes in the buffer
  for (i = 0; i < length; i = i + 84)
  {
    packet = (buffer + i);
    result = sendPacket(packet)
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit**:
I have also tried declaring packet like `char packet[84];` and get:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
     packet = (buffer + i);
            ^
```

Also, sendPacket is defined as:`sendPacket(char packet[84]);`

Comment: how is sendPacket defined

Comment: The type of `packet` is `char (*)[84]`. That is, it's a pointer to an array of 84 `char` elements. The type of `(buffer + i)` (which is also the exact same thing as `&buffer[i]`) is `char *`, i.e. a pointer to a single `char`. Why do you think those two types are the same? What are you trying to do?

Comment: he is trying to chop buffer up into 84 byte size chunks. Question is - exactly how is that chunk expected by sendPacket - char[84] or char * (with implict length)

Comment: Trying to update the memory location of the first byte in the `84 byte char array` to the memory location of `(buffer + i)`

Comment: how is sendPacket defined??

Comment: What I think you're trying to do is to pass the data pointed to by `buffer + i` to the `sendPacket` function. Unless the`sendPacket` have a very strange definition, I think it's enough to do `sendPacket(buffer + i)`. No need for the `packet` variable.

Comment: @pm100 doesn't matter, that's not the problem.  Sorry the sendPacket function is confusing I'll edit that.

Comment: how is sendPacket defined???? - i am typing the correct code for you, but I need to know what snedPAcket expects

Comment: i am trying to get OP's attention, next time ti will be in all caps

Comment: @pm100 just assume its defined as `sendPacket(char packet[84])`

Comment: is it defined like that or not? Makes a HUGE difference

Comment: @pm100 yes, with some extra params that are not relevant

Comment: First things first: you **can't assign an array** in C, no matter whether it's a regular one or a VLA. Typical solution: use `memcpy()` to copy the contents.

Comment: Whenever you see something like `char packet[size_is_irrelevant]` as a function arguments, it is *exactly* the same as `char *packet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
int result = 0;

// Iterate through all the bytes in the buffer
for (i = 0; i < length; i = i + 84)
{
  char packet[84];
  memcpy(packet, buffer[i],84);
  result = sendPacket(packet);
}

return 0;
```

note this does not deal with the case where buffer is not exact multiple of 84

life would be easier if sendPAcket expected `char *` rather that `char [84]`. Then code would read

```
int i = 0;
int result = 0; 

// Iterate through all the bytes in the buffer
for (i = 0; i < length; i = i + 84)
{
  char packet[84];
  memcpy(packet, buffer[i],84);
  result = sendPacket(buffer[i]);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: If the `sendPacket` function expects a `const char *` argument, why use a temporary array and the `memcpy` at all?

Comment: OP says its defined to take char[84]

Comment: @pm100 Pass-by-value on a buffer like that is missing the whole point of buffers.

Comment: Actually, that's equal to plain `char *`. So there is a chance the function might modify the data and then a temporary buffer might be needed. If it doesn't modify then no temporary buffer is needed.

Comment: I agree - but he says that sendPAcket is defined to take char[84]

Comment: @pm100 Good point that accepting char * might be better, I just have to make sure the code in sendPacket doesn't try to send more than 84 bytes.

Comment: so pass in a length

Comment: @pm100 Doesn't matter. For any array-like argument declaration, it's exactly equal to a non-array pointer declaration. Doesn't matter if there's a size or not, `char packet[84]` is exactly equal to `char *packet` for a function argument.

Comment: can you pass char * to a function that expects char[84]. I thought not, the other way round works for sure

Comment: just tried it - apparently you can pass char* to char[84] function. I am surprised

Comment: There's no need to copy the array here since you can just pass a pointer to the first element you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work:

```
packet = (buffer + i);
```

Because the types are not the same.  `packet` has type `char (*)[84]` (i.e. a pointer to an array of 84 `char`) while `buffer` has type `char *`.  You actually don't need this extra type.

Given that `sendPacket` is defined as:

```
int sendPacket(char packet[84])
```

The parameter `packet` actually has type `char *`, since arrays as function parameters *decay* into a pointer to the first element.

You can then call this function as follows:

```
result = sendPacket(buffer + i)
```

The expression `buffer + i` evaluates to the address of element `i` in the buffer.  Assuming `sendPacket` reads 84 bytes from this address, it will grab the next 84 bytes in the buffer.